# Have the kotlin invoke() function return a Deferred from Coroutine

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, deferred

The invoke function allows a function to be called directly from the class.

How can I get this to work with a Coroutine Deferred result?

I have tried below but am getting `Type mismatch Required: Deferred<List<MyModel>> Found: MyUseCase`

```
class MyUseCase(
    private val repository: MyRepository,
) {
    suspend operator fun invoke(id: String): Deferred<List<MyModel>> =
        CoroutineScope(IO).async {
            repository.fetchApi(id)
        }
    }
```

```
val deferredResult: Deferred<List<MyModel>> = viewModelUseCases.myUseCase
```

Comment: There’s no need for this function to be marked `suspend`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`invoke` allows an instance to be called as though it's a function, i.e. with parentheses. The `invoke` function you've written would be called by

```
val deferredResult: Deferred<List<MyModel>> = viewModelUseCases.myUseCase()
```